# Need additional information on how to access an INDD file using JavaScript

Tags: adobe, adobe-indesign

I am trying to read a bulk of Adobe Indesign (indd) files and access its content through a script.

I want to check the name of drawing files present in the project and fetch that information in a flat file.

Can anybody help me with this as I am new to this technology?

Comment: Please show us some code of what you have tried so far. We do not even know which scripting language you are referring to.

Comment: You may find [this resource](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/indesign/documentation.html) to be of use getting you started

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Please [edit] your question and post your code as a [mcve]! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to read the bytes from the indd files, you cannot. The indd is a binary blob and no one knows what data is stored where. 
If you are talking about getting list of placed files in the indd document, javascript can do that for you.
Step 1. Open the indd in indesign.
Step 2. the following script can return the path of each graphic in the doc

var grphx = app.activeDocument.allGraphics;

var i = 0;

for (i =0; i < grphx.length;++i)

{

```
alert(grphx[i].link.filePath);
```

}

Comment: Thanks manish for this valuable information. The problem with me is I have a bulk set of indd files in thousands. So I am looking for a method where I can do this thing explicitly without opening each and every indd file